# How to change post status from "draft" to "publish"?

Tags: post-status, wp-update-post

My script uses code to set post content.
I am also running the [WP To Twitter](https://www.joedolson.com/wp-to-twitter/) plugin, to auto-tweet those posts.

The problem is, whilst the plugin is correctly formulating its tweets using the default WordPress post fields, it is not using available *custom* post fields, nor the term name of a taxonomy to which the post is attached.

The theory, explored with the plugin author, is this - those custom fields and terms are getting saved **after** the post itself is published, meaning they are invisible at the point of tweeting.

It looks true. My code...

- uses `wp_insert_post` to save a post containing default fields as `post_status` `publish`
- then adds the custom fields using `update_field`
- and then sets the taxonomy terms.

Author advises a tweak to my code:

- save the default post fields instead as `draft`
- then add the custom fields using `update_field`
- and only *then* change the post status to `publish`

In the excerpt from my script below, I have attempted to make the change - changing to `draft` and adding a `wp_update_post` in both `if` clauses.

This works, to a point - I can see the script is now setting new posts as `draft`.

**What is not working, however, is the transfer of these posts to `publish`, they remain in `draft`. This is what I need to solve - to ensure that they can be set as `publish`.**

What is going wrong with `wp_update_post` and the `my_post` array? Does the order of the values in the array matter? Like, should `ID` come first? Is the problem not setting `post_date` or `post_date_gmt`?

And would it be better/different to use `wp_publish_post` instead of `wp_update_post`? I read there are some discrepancies.

```
            //if quote is not found in the quotes custom post type
            //it will create new quotes and save it in to the db
            if($quote_id == 0){

                echo "Quote is not found. Creating new quote<br />";

                $customPostParams = array ( 'post_author' => $user_id,

                                            'post_type' => 'quote',

                                            'post_title' => $story['title'],

                                            'post_content' => $body,

                                            // WP To Twitter plugin fires on publish and can only see published post data.
                                            // Quote story_* fields, Source terms, Company terms and Product $firm_terms are set
                                            // after saving.
                                            // So, let's save as draft, set those items and only publish when all items are available.
                                            'post_status' => 'draft', // was: 'publish'

                                            'post_date' => $story['published_at']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),

                                            'post_date_gmt' => $story['published_at']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),

                                            'comment_status' => 'closed',

                                            'ping_status' => 'closed' );


                $post_id = wp_insert_post($customPostParams);

                update_field('story_id', $story['id'], $post_id);

                update_field('story_permalink', $story['links']['permalink'], $post_id);

                update_field('story_language', $story['language'], $post_id);

                update_source_and_connect_to_quote($post_id, $story);

                update_companies_and_connect_to_quote($post_id, $story, $firmName, $firm_alternate_name);

                update_product_and_connect_to_quote($post_id, $story);

                // Change from draft to published
                $my_post = array(
                  'post_type' => 'quote',
                  'ID'           => $quote_id,
                  'post_status'   => 'publish',
                );
                // Update the post into the database
                wp_update_post( $my_post );


            } else {

                //if quotes already found then it will update that quote
                echo "Quote is found. Updating existing quote<br />";

                echo "Title: {$story['title']} <br />";

                $customPostParams = array ( 'ID' => $quote_id,

                                            'post_author' => $user_id,

                                            'post_type' => 'quote',

                                            'post_title' => $story['title'],

                                            'post_content' => $body,

                                            'post_status' => 'draft',

                                            'post_date' => $story['published_at']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),

                                            'post_date_gmt' => $story['published_at']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),

                                            'comment_status' => 'closed',

                                            'ping_status' => 'closed' );

                wp_update_post( $customPostParams );

                update_field('story_id', $story['id'], $quote_id);

                update_field('story_permalink', $story['links']['permalink'], $quote_id);

                update_field('story_language', $story['language'], $quote_id);

                update_source_and_connect_to_quote($quote_id, $story);

                update_companies_and_connect_to_quote($quote_id, $story, $firmName, $firm_alternate_name);

                update_product_and_connect_to_quote($quote_id, $story);

                // Change from draft to published
                $my_post = array(
                  'post_type' => 'quote',
                  'ID'           => $quote_id,
                  'post_status'   => 'publish',
                );
                // Update the post into the database
                wp_update_post( $my_post );


            }
```

Comment: hmmm `update_field` is not a WordPress API? Also are you aware that if you don't pass an ID to `wp_update_post` it will create the post? It's just a wrapper around `wp_insert_post`, you should be able to reduce your codes size in half trivially

Comment: @TomJNowell 1. Good point/question re `update_field` - it is Advanced Custom Fields' function for updating ACF fields. But it works okay and saves them fine, the problem is `post_status` thereafter.  2. But I am passing an ID to `wp_update_post`, I think.  3. Don't understand the code reduction point.

Comment: Got a feeling my `quote_id` in `$my_post` should be `post_id`. Going to try that.

Answer (score 2):

A two-part answer below -

As above: the broad solution was to save the posts first as draft, then update them with the custom fields and terms, and only then set them to publish.

As I said, the above code modification had succeeded in setting the posts to `draft` but not in transitioning them to `publish`, they were stuck.

1. Indeed, I was using the wrong variable in the first `if` clause. **Solution**: In the array feeding `wp_update_post()`, changing `'ID' => $quote_id,` to `'ID' => $post_id,` succeeded in helping the posts transition to `publish` at the end. This was just a mistake on my part, really.
2. However, then the WP To Twitter plugin was not seeing the post at all as `publish` was fired. **Solution**: It took changing the method of status transitioning from `wp_update_post` to `wp_publish_post` to make it see everything...

That is, from...

```
                // Change from draft to published
                $my_post = array(
                  'ID'           => $post_id,
                  'post_type' => 'quote',
                  'post_status'   => 'publish',
                );
                // Update the post into the database
                wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

to...

```
                wp_publish_post( $post_id );
```

After doing that, it now **looks** like it works out okay - the plugin is tweeting out all the post fields (standard and custom) that I need.

It would be useful to read some things about the differences between `wp_update_post` and `wp_publish_post`, because I had read [some information on here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/208318/39300) about discrepancies, with a recommendation to use the former.